# Subclassed UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uikit, scrollview

Is there a way to get a notification for the different UIScrollView delegate methods inside the subclassed scrollview without setting "self.delegate = self"? I need to get notification for certain events inside my subclass, but I still need certain other events to be sent to the delegate. So unfortunately I can't assign two objects as delegate. Are there ways to do this otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your subclass has a weak property - oldDelegate - and when the delegate is set (you detect this in a subclassed setDelegate method), you actually set oldDelegate instead, then make yourself the delegate.

Implement all the delegate methods and send each to "oldDelegate".